# What can cause a firefox is already running pop up - Ubuntu

Tags: firefox, ubuntu, web

I've installed a monitoring web app to a client a while ago. We use Firefox to run it and it appears that we keep having a "Firefox is already running, but is not responding" popup on the client side. Sometimes it works well, and sometimes, we're not even able to restart Firefox.

As we're on a Ubuntu system, I can do a

```
killall -9 firefox && firefox
```

to restart Firefox but I would prefer to know why this problem is happening.

Do you know how I can investigate this issue ? Are they some Firefox dev-mods or crash logs I can enable to get some infos about why it's not responding ?

Some technical stuff about the web app which could help I suppose:
- it's working with  Django 1.5 threw Apache2
- it uses ajax with Mootools to refresh regularly (it's a monitoring system)

Thanks in advance, and tell me if you need any other details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out what was wrong : we were using a VNC connexion to see X and it appears that Firefox has difficulties managing display on two X instances

Comment: You can use `firefox -no-remote` to force it to work in this case.